How to run a project built with boost on a machine without boost?
I use visual studio. The project is assembled and launched on a Linux machine. but if you run it on a machine where boost is not installed, the error "error while loading shared libraries libboost_thread.so.1.67.0: can open shared file" is displayed.
How can I somehow assemble a project using visual studio so that it statically links all the dependencies for boost?
I added libboost_thread.so.1.67.0 to the linker->input->Additional Dependencies, and the build was successful, but when running on a device without boost installed, the error remained.

I use visual studio 2015.

You can use static linking. The program will get larger. And you should be careful if you also want to load other libraries that use boost

Should the Additional Dependencies option link statically?

It's an additional dependency alright, but the static one is probably different. I don't know whether MSVC builds both at the same time, but look here for hints: runtime-link=static

I mixed up static and dynamic libraries in Linux. In linker->input->Additional Dependencies you need to add libboost_thread.a

If that worked please post it as an answer so other people can find it

I mixed up static and dynamic libraries in Linux. In linker->input->Additional Dependencies you need to add libboost_thread.a
